# How do I convert a String into doubles to compute average in Java?

Tags: java, string, average

I need help with an assignment. There are many similar questions on here, but those answers are not working for me so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The assignment is "The program prompts the user for five to ten numbers, all on one line, and separated by spaces.  Then the program calculates the average of those numbers, and displays the numbers and their average to the user."

We need to call to different methods to do this. The part that's giving me problems is converting the String to doubles and finding the average. We also need to validate that there are between 5-10 numbers in the String (I can validate it once I get it to count properly). I've tried a few things, including answers to similar questions on here (shown in code below), but the only output I get is 0.0.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
              
        String getNumbers = "";
        double calcAverage = 0;
        
        getNumbers();
        calcAverage(getNumbers);
        System.out.println(calcAverage);
                
    }
    
    public static String getNumbers() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 to 10 numbers separated by spaces: ");
        String getNumbers = scnr.next();
        
        return getNumbers;
    }

    
public static double calcAverage(String userNumbers){

        double calcAverage = 0.0;
        double i = 0;
        double count = 0.0;
        
        Scanner str = new Scanner(userNumbers);
        
        while (str.hasNextDouble()){
            count++;
            i = i + str.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("count=" + count); //test to check it is counting properly
        calcAverage = i/count;
        return calcAverage;
    }
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Sorry Zephyr, I didn't clarify. The assignment wants us to use a while loop. I did see the method you wrote as a possibility, but it doesn't fit the assignment requirements unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and post your [mcve]. Without knowing the format of the `userNumbers` string that's being passed to this method, it's hard to test.

Comment: @Zephyr, I will add more code now. This is my first time asking a question and I wasn't sure what to add

Comment: No worries, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to read the link I posted as it is really important for this site. It might seem like overkill at times, but trust me: it will always lead to more helpful answers. :)

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks! I will read. The rest of the code is up.

Comment: Can use Double.parseDouble(String) to do parsing

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an error in your main method and need to set the getNumbers equal to the getNumbers method and the same with the calcaverage double with the calcaverage method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
              
        String getNumbers = "";
        double calcAverage = 0;
        
        getNumbers();
        calcAverage(getNumbers);
        System.out.println(calcAverage);
                
    }
```

should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
              
        String getNumbers = "";
        double calcAverage = 0;
        
        getNumbers =getNumbers();
        calcAverage =calcAverage(getNumbers);
        System.out.println(calcAverage);
                
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! It's always something I thought I had right lol...

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to make it more readable and avoid and external iterations

```java
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import java.util.OptionalDouble;


class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    OptionalDouble optAvg = calcAverage("2 5 6 7 8 9 0 1");

    if (optAvg.isPresent()) {
      System.out.println("optAvg.getAsDouble() = " + optAvg.getAsDouble());
    }

  }

  public static OptionalDouble calcAverage(String userNumbers) {

    String[] inputArr = userNumbers.split(" ");
    int count = inputArr.length;

    System.out.println("count = " + count);

    if (count < 5 || count > 10) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Or do some other this here!");
    }

    return stream(inputArr)
        .mapToDouble(
            Double::parseDouble) // throws a NumberFormatException if it can't convert to Double
        .average();
  }
}
```

Or even simpler

```java
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics;


class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    DoubleSummaryStatistics doubleSummaryStatistics = calcAverage("2 5 6 7 8 9 0 1");
    System.out.println("count = " + doubleSummaryStatistics.getCount());
    System.out.println("average = " + doubleSummaryStatistics.getAverage());
  }

  public static DoubleSummaryStatistics calcAverage(String userNumbers) {
    return stream(userNumbers.split(" "))
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .summaryStatistics();
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you did this, but I have not learned a lot of what you put in there yet, so I unfortunately cannot use it unless I want my teacher to know I asked for help lol

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String numberString = getNumbers();
    double averageNum = calcAverage(numberString);
    System.out.println(averageNum);
            
}

public static String getNumbers() {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter 5 to 10 numbers separated by spaces: ");
    String getNumbers = scnr.nextLine();
    
    return getNumbers;
}


public static double calcAverage(String userNumbers){

    double calcAverage = 0.0;
    double i = 0;
    double count = 0.0;
    
    Scanner str = new Scanner(userNumbers);
    
    while (str.hasNextDouble()){
        count++;
        i = i + str.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("count=" + count); //test to check it is counting properly
    calcAverage = i/count;
    return calcAverage;
}
```

A few changes, but you had it right for the most part. Going from the top of the file:

- Removed getNumbers and calcAverage
- Added numberString and averageNum (when you call functions with return, you need to store the value that it returns into a variable)
- changed line:

```java
String getNumbers = scnr.next();
```

to:

```java
String getNumbers = scnr.nextLine();
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you!! So was the main issue that I had ```String getNumbers = scnr.next();``` instead of ```String getNumbers = scnr.nextLine();``` ??

Comment: Exactly! A very minor error, great job otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with supplied values validation :

```
public static double calcAverage(String userNumbers) {
    double calcAverage = 0.0;
    double i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner str = new Scanner(userNumbers.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));

    while (str.hasNext()) {
        String val = str.next();
        // Is the supplied numerical value valid?
        if (!val.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            //No...
            System.out.println("Supplied value of " + val + 
                    " is ignored since it is not a valid numerical value!");
            continue;
        }
        count++;  // count now that we know the value is indeed valid.
        i += Double.parseDouble(val);
        
    }
    
    System.out.println("count=" + count); //test to check it is counting properly
    calcAverage = i / count;
    return calcAverage;
}
```

Since you are processing a supplied whitespace delimited string of ***hopefully*** numerical values you can merely utilize the the [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) method in conjunction with the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method.

**Preparing the Scanner object:**

```
Scanner str = new Scanner(userNumbers.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

Here we take the string contained within the supplied `userNumbers` string variable and trim off any possible leading and trailing white-spaces, we don't want these if there are any. We also replace any portion of the supplied string that *may* contain **more** than a single whitespace with just a single whitespace. We want to enforce this format before we proceed so as to help with eliminating any *possible* type of conflict later on in method code. You can't always rely on the User to provide everything perfectly all the time so if you can help then it's worth it.

**Retrieving each supplied value from the supplied String:**

```
while (str.hasNext()) {
    String val = str.next();
    // ... other code ...
}
```

The `hasNext()` method will allow the loop to continue for as long as there is another whitespace delimited string token to process. In this case we're hoping that each token will be a string representation of a numerical value.

Because the `hasNext()` method has let us get this far into the loop we know there is another String token available. The `str.next()` call retrieves that available token and in this case, is placing that string token into the string variable named `val`. This is done upon each iteration of the `while` loop until there are no more tokens remaining to process.

**Validating a retrieved string token:**

```
if (!val.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) { ... }
```

Validation of each string token is done here utilizing the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a specific [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) of `"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"`. When passed in the `matches()` method, this regex checks to see if the string it is played against is indeed a string representation of a signed or unsigned integer or floating point numerical value:

```
-?            Optional. Value is prefixed with '-'.
\\d+          One or more digits.
(\\.\\d+)?    Optional. Value is post-fixed with a decimal point 
              and one or more digits.
```

In this case we're checking to see if the token is **invalid** and if it is we supply a message to the console window indicating as such and the fact that this token value will be ignored. We ignore it by using the **continue** keyword which forces the `while` loop into it's next iteration and bypassing the remaining code within the loop.

**Converting a String numerical value to a Double data type:**

```
count++;  // count now that we know the value is indeed valid.
i+= Double.parseDouble(val);
```

We do the count ***after*** knowing the value provided is indeed valid. `i` was previously declared as a double type and sums the token numerical value after it is converted to double with the [Double.parseDouble()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm) method. Using `i +=` is the very same as `i = i +`.

---

**Another shorter way:**

```
public static double calcAverage(String userNumbers) {
    double calcAverage = 0.0;
    double i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner str = new Scanner(userNumbers.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
    while (str.hasNextDouble()) {
        double val = str.nextDouble();
        count++; 
        i+= val;
    }
    
    System.out.println("count=" + count); //test to check it is counting properly
    calcAverage = i / count;
    return calcAverage;
}
```